# How to dynamically update scala variable in view, play 2.2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

I know variable can be declared in views as

```
@import java.lang.String; var message= "Error"
```

How can I update this var dynamically? If I do @(message=result), result being javascript variable updated from api, I get error

> not found: value result

Comment: You seems to misunderstanding the way JS and server-side can work togather.

Comment: i think you are messing different parts. can you give us a more detailed source code? but as @cchantep said, there are server variables and javascript(client) variables...

Comment: I know what you are saying, my approach is definitely not right and thats what I am trying to ask.. When a scala var is declared like above I can use it in Javascript  like var test=@message; but can I change the value of scala variable message??

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible. The Scala code runs server side, generates a HTTP response which is served to your browser. Play is done at that point.

Your JS code runs client-side, operating on the web page that is already generated and loaded by the browser. The only way to communicate to the Play application is by sending a HTTP request ('ajax') from JS. That is a separate request though, and all state from the preceding request is already gone at that point.